# Dismiss last ViewController after the new ViewController is presented

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I open the same ViewController with a different variable, in case that is important:

```
@IBAction func buttonNextPostTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //let postCount = posts.count
    //let postNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ..< postCount)
    let currentVC = presentingViewController
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainApplication", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostsViewController") as! PostsViewController
    //nextViewController.post = posts[postNumber]
    nextViewController.isFromRandom = true
    self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        currentVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
        })
    }
```

When I tap the button, a new VC appears and the old VC moves to the background. When I tap the button multiple times, I have a lot VC in the background.

How can I dismiss the previous VC, when the new VC is presented, so I will not have a lot of VCs in the background?

Edit: With the current code, everything gets dismissed.

Comment: Judging from the name of your button, I think you need a `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Are you sure? I could have a n-amount of next VCs

Comment: If the old view controller is truly in the background you shouldn't be dismissing it in an "animated" fashion. At what point are you setting the presentingViewController? It would make sense to set it after you present it.